# Error updating fusion table from forms

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to use forms to input data into a fusion table and I'm following the [instructions here](http://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/instructions.html), which say to use [this App script](http://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/appsscript.js).

When I run it, I get this error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 21, file "Code")`

All the "how to" pages I find link back to the instructions I'm using.

Could it be the suggested app script needs to be updated for the newer fusion table API? In searching for an answer I found others with the same problem. Has anyone updated this script for the new fusion table API?

A page on migrating to new API says "Note: This script uses the deprecated SQL API. Please use the migration guide to modify your script to use the v1 API."

Although I'm pretty good at following technical instructions exactly, modifying JavaScript is beyond me.